# For List or Map type state, BlocBuilder not updating

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-bloc

I have initialized state with a blank list. You can see equitable is here for state compare

[image: I have initialized state with a blank list. You can see equitable is here for state compare.]

Here is the cubit for updating state. I am just getting a random number and adding it into the list. Number is adding but bloc build not updating

[image: Here is the cubit for updating state. I am just getting a random number and adding it into the list. Number is adding but bloc build not updating]

I am adding number from UI in this way. You can see state is updating in Debug Console.

[image: I am adding number from UI in this way. You can see state is updating in Debug Console.]

For single number, string, Boolean etc. state case is ok. But I don't know why for map/list or object this is not working. Please help me what should I do in this case.

Comment: I believe you have to create a new `List` like this, `state.number.toList()..add(num)` or `[...state.number, num]` in `addNumber()` of your `NumberCubit`. The thing is the `Equatable` was always receiving the same `List` instance which it considers the same.

Comment: yes it's working now after adding .toList(), thanks a lot.

Comment: Or you can simply change the `props()` of the `NumberState` like `List<Object> get props => [...number];` so that it looks at the elements of the `List` rather than the `List` object itself.